# Why is PostgreSQL 11 optimizer refusing best plan which would use an index w/ included column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, sql-execution-plan

PostgreSQL 11 isn't smart enough to use indexes with included columns?

```
CREATE INDEX organization_locations__org_id_is_headquarters__inc_location_id_ix
ON organization_locations(org_id, is_headquarters) INCLUDE (location_id);

ANALYZE organization_locations;
ANALYZE organizations;

EXPLAIN VERBOSE
SELECT location_id
FROM organization_locations ol
WHERE org_id = (SELECT id FROM organizations WHERE code = 'akron')
AND is_headquarters = 1;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on organization_locations ol  (cost=8.44..14.61 rows=1 width=4)
  Output: ol.location_id
  Filter: ((ol.org_id = $0) AND (ol.is_headquarters = 1))
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using organizations__code_ux on organizations  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4)
          Output: organizations.id
          Index Cond: ((organizations.code)::text = 'akron'::text)
```

There are only 211 rows currently in organization_locations, average row length 91 bytes.

I get only loading one data page. But the I/O is the same to grab the index page and the target data is right there (no extra lookup into the data page from the index). What is PG thinking with this plan?

This just creates a TODO for me to round back and check to make sure the right plan starts getting generated once the table burgeons.

EDIT: Here is the explain with buffers:

```
Seq Scan on organization_locations ol  (cost=8.44..14.33 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.018..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: ((org_id = $0) AND (is_headquarters = 1))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 210
  Buffers: shared hit=7
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using organizations__code_ux on organizations  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ((code)::text = 'akron'::text)
          Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning Time: 0.402 ms
Execution Time: 0.048 ms
```

Comment: For only 211 rows, a Seq Scan is most probably the most efficient way to do it. Check the plan generated `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: No question about a Seq Scan being usually faster with small number of rows. In this case the scan hit 7 pages, the index 4.

Comment: Shrug. You still haven't provided a detailed execution plan as I suggested - which would show those figures. But you can't derive the execution plan used for large tables by looking at the execution plan that was generated with small tables.

Comment: Oh shoot. Sorry. I didn't realize you wanted to see it. I'll edit the main post with that.

Answer (score 4):

Reading one index page is not cheaper than reading a table page, so with tiny tables you cannot expect a gain from an index-only scan.

Besides, did you

```
VACUUM organization_locations;
```

Without that, the visibility map won't show that the table block is all-visible, so you cannot get an index-only scan no matter what.

Comment: Yes on Vacuum. Can you give more color on your statement? I'm hearing you say it's more expensive in PG to read an index page than a table page? How is that?

Comment: I said that it is not cheaper, I didn't say it is more expensive. However, depending on your setting of `random_page_cost`, the optimizer might estimate it more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, this is probably a silly index to have in the first place.  INCLUDE is good when you need a unique index but you also want to tack on a column which is not part of the unique constraint, or when the included column doesn't have btree operators and so can't be in the main body of the index.  In other cases, you should just put the extra column in the index itself.

> This just creates a TODO for me to round back and check to make sure the right plan starts getting generated once the table burgeons.

This is your workflow problem that you can't expect PostgreSQL to solve for you.  Do you really think PostgreSQL should create actual plans based on imaginary scenarios?

Comment: I disagree on the use of INCLUDE only for unique indexes. I know this feature is new to PG, but it has saved a TON of I/O in SQL Server applications (which has had that feature forever). This is especially true when the row lengths are large. Also, I would never add columns I want to include onto the index column list just to get it included in the index. That would create an excess of branch pages with no benefit.

Comment: As far as imaginary scenarios- no, I don't expect that. I expect a cheaper (I/O) plan to be favored. I get I could probably tweak server level cost parameters, but that is a blunt instrument. Boy, if only PG supported hints. But don't get me started on why the PG community is so fiercing against hints, when in a crisis (not normal design/dev) they can truely save your bacon.

Comment: Wait. Are you saying included columns will be part of the index? That is, branch pages will be created for distinct values of included columns? That's not how other dbs work. The include is to save I/O, not become part of the index.

Comment: @quickdraw Obviously included columns need to be "part of the index" - what's the benefit of including them if they are not included in the index? And it's pretty useless to compare the actual implementation that one DB system uses with another. Especially when it comes to internals the different products are very different.

Comment: There is a difference between including the columns in the btree structure, and including columns in the leaf pages. I don't expect included columns are part of the branching structure.

Comment: While suffix truncation is easier on INCLUDE columns, it can still be done on regular index columns, which recent versions of PostgreSQL do.  And if it didn't, how wide is a column named "location_id" going to be that it changes the fan-out factor in an important way?  I'll believe the change in IO is huge when I see the evidence.